# Wrong date displayed on 'Newest' question list on User Profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

The ['Newest' question list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=questions&sort=newest) on a User Profile page displays 'last activity date' but sorts by the original 'asked date'.

This is confusing because when I click 'Newest' I expect displayed dates to be in chronological order (date asked descending) but they are not. There is also no *obvious* rhyme or reason to the dates that are displayed.

Would it make more sense to change the displayed date to the original 'Asked' date because that is what the list is being sorted by?

We already have the 'Activity' list for questions if we want them sorted by last activity date.

[image]